# LAB: Output values in a list below a user defined amount

Tags: python

Write a program that first gets a list of integers from input. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers that follow. Then, get the last value from the input, which indicates a threshold. Output all integers less than or equal to that last threshold value.

Ex: If the input is:

```
5
50
60
140
200
75
100
```

the output is:

```
50,60,75,
```

The 5 indicates that there are five integers in the list, namely 50, 60, 140, 200, and 75. The 100 indicates that the program should output all integers less than or equal to 100, so the program outputs 50, 60, and 75.

For coding simplicity, follow every output value by a comma, including the last one.

Such functionality is common on sites like Amazon, where a user can filter results.

My code is:

```
n = int(input())
user_values =[]

def get_user_values():
    for i in range(n):
        num = int(input())
        user_values.append(num)
        upper_threshold=user_values[-1]
    return user_values, upper_threshold
 
def output_ints_less_than_or_equal_to_threshold(user_values, upper_threshold):
    user_values = [i for i in user_values if i <= upper_threshold]
    print(*user_values, sep = "\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_values, upper_threshold = get_user_values()
    output_ints_less_than_or_equal_to_threshold(user_values, upper_threshold)
```

With inputs:

```
7
25
30
47
28
27
25
31
30
```

My output:

```
25
30
28
27
25
31
```

But my expected output:

```
25,30,28,27,25,
```

Comment: That's what the site's for...

Comment: Gregory: Questions like that are off-topic for this site, even in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def output_ints_less_than_or_equal_to_threshold(user_values, upper_threshold):
    for value in user_values:
        if value <= upper_threshold:
            print(value, end="," ) 
    
def get_user_values():
    n = int(input())
    lst = []
    for i in range(n):
        lst.append(int(input()))
    return lst  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    userValues = get_user_values()
    upperThreshold = int(input())
    output_ints_less_than_or_equal_to_threshold(userValues, upperThreshold)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting the following routine:

1. Read the nr of inputs
2. Read the input numbers (in the code below, they will be appended to the `list`)
3. Read the threshold
4. Filter the list

```py
list = []
result = []
n = int(input()) # 1

for i in range(n): # 2
   number = int(input())
   list.append(number)

threshold = int(input()) # 3

# --- The following is one way of filtering the list, it checks every entry and either appends it to the result-list or ignores it
for i in list: # 4
   if i <= threshold:
       print(i, end=",")
       result.append(i)
```

In the `result` variable, you will find your answer

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

First time writing the code here, (I am a newbie).

```
user_values = []
def get_user_values(n):
    for i in range(n):
        # print(i)
        num = int(input())
        user_values.append(num)
    upper_threshold = int(input())
    return user_values, upper_threshold

def ints_less_than_or_equal_to_threshold(user_values, upper_threshold):    
    re_value = [i for i in user_values if i<= upper_threshold]
    for new_list in re_value:
        print(new_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    user_values, upper_threshold = get_user_values(n)
    re_value = ints_less_than_or_equal_to_threshold(user_values, upper_threshold)
```